# How to make a non-editable object editable

Tags: c#, object

This is how my class object looks like:

```
Class MyInfo :IDisposable
{
    List<MYObject> list;

    public long X { get; private set; }
        public IList<RasterFieldInfo> FieldInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _ fields.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

I do have an object MyInfo which is read-only (no public setter), I am looking an efficient way to make it writeable.
I cannot make this object as writeable (i.e. I cannot make setters as public) because that will give an impression to user that he is making changes to original object (while that is not true) and due to other reasons. What I am looking for is:

1. Minimal code duplication, this class has lots of code inside it.
2. Ease of use for the person going to use this object.
3. Best possible design and implementation.
4. I cannot make any setters as public to make it writeable.

Editable object usage will be as follows:

```
MyInfo obj = ds.GetInfo();
MyInfo editableObj = Obj.CreateEditableObject(); 
….
//Modify members of editableObj
…
Ds.SetInfo(editableObj);
```

Issue is how to provide an editable object of the same type by calling CreateEditableObject method.

Comment: Make setters public, but raise error on writing these, unless object is marked editable.

Comment: I think you should be looking at the builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern (sadly I don't remember how its called)

```
class MyInfo
{
    public int MyProperty{ get; private set; }

    public MyInfo WithMyProperty(int value)
    {
       return new MyInfo(){ MyProperty = value };
    }
}


MyInfo obj = ds.GetInfo();
MyInfo modified = obj.WithMyProperty(1234);
```

The original object is of course not modified.

Comment: This would create a new object each time you want to adjust another variable. The builder pattern would solve this a lot more elegantly by preparing the object and returning it when you want it.

Comment: I doubt that it will solve my problem, as it will be able to create new object but still it is not making new object editable.

Comment: I won't be able to pass all the values that I would like to edit to WithMyProperty as they are many. I want WithMyProperty to clone the object and later I want to set values of private members of the cloned object (at present I cant do that because cloned object is also of type MyInfo and its all setters are private).